# Can I change the looks of only the lowercase/uppercase characters in a line of text?

Tags: css

Imagine that you have some text like this: "Asdf"

I want the 'A' to be bigger than the rest of the text without having to do some evil CSS hacks with multiple divs and whatnot.

And I was thinking that if you could change the properties of ONLY the uppercase letters, then I would be able to set the font-size to something bigger than the rest, and thus get a bigger A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `first-letter` pseudo selector. It's not fully cross browser though (I think).

Quirksmode has a compatibility chart and some details : http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/firstline.html

Comment: This was my first thought as well, but the problem is that this will only transform the first letter of a paragraph to whatever you tell it to, but not influence letters that are uppercase in HTML (and they needn't be the first in the paragraph).

Comment: hmm, I don't think that's even possible. If you used JS you'd have to go through them all or use a regex to match

Comment: Even if this is not **exactly** what I looked for, it fixes my problem! As it was only going to be used in links like the one in my picture, I actually didn't need anything other than the first-letter pseudo selector. I made it sound more complicated than what it needed to be! :) So thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can use a font containing only the enlarged uppercase character, and let the browser's own font fallback mechanism to use that font only for the uppercase letters. The `font-family` property would look something like:

```
font-family: 'large-georgia', Georgia, serif;
```

`@font-face` or data URL can be used to provide the font. The technique is the same as that used in the [this article](http://24ways.org/2009/spruce-it-up), only we're now using  a set of capital letters instead of an ampersand.